# Evaluating a kronecker delta product

Tags: kronecker-product

Say I have a product, $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}q_{n}r_{k}\delta_{n-1,k-1}$. How do I evaluate this?

I've tried opening up the $n$ summation, which gives me, $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \left( q_{0} r_{k} \delta_{-1, k-1} + q_{1} r_{k} \delta_{0, k - 1} + \cdots \right)$. I'm at a loss as to how to proceed further.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** In your expanded sum, how many terms are non-zero?

Comment: @BenGrossmann If I just look at the first term, and readjust the indices ($k \rightarrow k +1$), the summation starts from $k = -1$. So it gives a $\delta_{-1,k}$, and only the $k = -1$ term survives. Similar logic for the other terms in the summation applies. Essentially the original sum reduces to $q_{n+1} r_{n+1}$, with $n$ running from $-1 \rightarrow +\infty$. Right?

Comment: That's right ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks!